# Why doesn't "overflow:hidden" work on siblings with position properties?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I made several tests with the property overflow:hidden.

I wonder why it doesn't work if I apply it to .child1
If I apply to #parent it only works on #section2, but child2 remains covered

I wonder which are the causes of this behaviour and what to do in order to fix it.

I found out that the overflow:hidden works on sibligns (if I apply the property to #parent, its sibling(#section2) gets uncovered.

However it does not work on siblings (child1) and (child2). If I apply the property either to child1 or #parent, child2 remains covered by child1.

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="parent">
    <div class="child1"> <strong>child1</strong></div>
    <div class="child2"><strong>child2</strong></div>
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
    <p> I am section2</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: overflow: hidden does not apply to siblings. What you see when you give parent overflow: hidden is that child1 is confined to the height of parent, it does not go below it so you see section. overflow: hidden on child1 or child2 will have no effect at all in your example as neither has content that overflows. In brief, overflow: hidden stops a particular element's contents from overflowing that element's bounds.

Comment: So, if I apply "overflow:hidden" to child1, only child1's children would be affected and not child2, its siblings right? If I want to prevent the child1's content from overflowing to child2 I have to find other ways.

Comment: Yes that’s right.